# How can I force values of SSRS parameter to run in order entered?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report that takes multiple values for a parameter.  Currently, I can enter in the values for the parameter (order #s) in any order, but it will order them alphanumerically.  I do not want this, I want them to run in the order given.  How can I force this?

Let me know if you need more context.

Comment: When you say "I can enter the values in any order" are you referring to setting the Available Values for the parameter?  Or are you referring to the end-user typing in multiple values?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the order using the Report Data controls.

[image]

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255258.aspx)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: shoot, probably bad phrasing on my part.  I have one parameter, it takes multiple values.